# Using many timers may cause application crash?

Tags: c#, timer

I have an application and I have 6 timers. each timer have different interval which mean 1s, 1s, 3s, 3s, 3s, 3s, respectively. Require CPU is always 2% to 3%.
in my PC is fine due to my PC's capability.

I am sure it may cause application if PC's capability is low.

Is there any effective way to use timer? or other running background?
The reason, I use timer because this timer will query database(get total amount) whenever user added or edit or delete product record, not just product record any record.

Timer 1s is for show Date and Time label
Timer 1s is to interact with datagriview, update the whole column
and Other timers is to get data from MySql Server. As my estimation, the max num of records can be 10 records.

Thanks

Comment: Will many timers themselfs cause an application to crash?, No. Does your application crash? if so what is the error, that should tell you the problem. One concern would be if your 1s timer queries the DB and the query takes longer than one second to you have logic in place to handle that if required

Comment: only 3s timers, will query database. (for not mention this).
As right now, it doesnot crash yet but I am thinking it may crash or working very slow.

Comment: Can you describe what process these timers are running?  If it's doing some sort of reporting, you probably don't need to update it quite that often.

Comment: Running only small amounts timers will not crash your application, but long running queries running every 3 seconds may have performance issues on slow machines or bad network DB setups. If it does crash its not the Timers its the implementation of the code inside the timers event.Perhaps setting up a nive DAL to the DB will be a better option and you could use DB triggers or StateChanges to update the UI.

Comment: What happen if the query takes more time than the timers `interval` ? do you run it again ?

Comment: Why don't you poll every 30 seconds? 3 seconds sounds like overkill. If you really need data that often, and the data is only changed when a client updates it, you could broadcast changes to all clients when they happen. If you have to pull lots of data every 3 seconds as a hard requirement, you're in trouble.

Comment: Mille Smith: you are right. that's why I am thinking of another way to improve this.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear why you think you need multiple timers here, and you don't even say which timer implementation you are using - and it would likely make a difference.

Employing a single timer that triggers on a reasonable minimal precision (1s, 100ms, etc) would reduce the overall overhead and would likely serve your purpose better. Of course that's said without any indication of what your actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you may have multiple issues, but to answer your question, running multiple timers will no cause your application to crash. How you implement the timers and if you are locking the code blocks that are called when a time is fired are important. If you are allowing code blocks to be executed before the code block has finished executing a previous call it can cause your application to become unstable. You should look at timers and perhaps even threads. Without knowing more about what you are doing it is difficult to provide a an more definitive answer to your question.